# Moving to different servlet other than form action

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am having a form :

```
<form action="sendaddnotification" method="post">
        <%String namee=rs.getString(2);%>
<input name="IndUserName"  type="hidden" value="<%=namee%>"/>
User Name : <%=namee%>
<br>
First Name : <%=rs.getString(4)%> 
    <br>

Last Name : <%=rs.getString(5)%>
    <br>

Email Id : <%=rs.getString(6)%>
    <br>

Contact : <%=rs.getString(7)%>
   <br>
   <%
   String groupidd = request.getSession().getAttribute("groupid").toString();
   s=null;
   rs=null;
   int flag=0;
   String sql="select * from TBGROUPUSERS where I_ID=? and GU_GROUPID=?";

    s = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    s.setString(1,idperson);
    s.setString(2,groupidd);
    rs=s.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next())
    flag=1;
    request.setAttribute("flag", flag);
   %>

<c:choose>
<c:when test="${requestScope.flag == 1}">
    <!-- flag is 1 -->
    <input type="submit" value="REQUEST SENT" disabled="disabled"></input>
    <a href="CancelRequest?userid=<%=idperson%>&userrnamee=<%=namee%>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel the request?');">
    <input type="submit" value="CANCEL REQUEST"></input>
    </a>

</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    <!-- flag isn't 1 -->
    <input type="submit" value="ADD"></input>
</c:otherwise>

</c:choose>


<a href="searchdatabasetoadd.jsp"><input type="button" value="BACK"></input></a>

</form>
```

Now ,In this part of code :

```
<a href="CancelRequest?userid=<%=idperson%>&userrnamee=<%=namee%>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel the request?');">
    <input type="submit" value="CANCEL REQUEST"></input>
    </a>
```

I want to move to servlet CancelRequest.java with this given parameters.But as the form action goes to sendaddnotification,So this servlet never runs.

How to make it run on click of this button.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CancelRequest servlet is defined in web.xml as:

```
    <servlet>
         <servlet-name>cancelRequest</servlet-name>
         <servlet-path>packageName.CancelRequest</servlet-path>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>cancelRequest</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/cancelRequest</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Write javascript function as:

```
    function cancelRequest(){
        var exit = confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel the request?');
        if(exit == true){
            document.getElementById('sendaddnotificationId').action = 'cancelRequest';
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
```

Include id for form in jsp as:

```
    <form action="sendaddnotification" id="sendaddnotificationId" method="post">
```

And change anchor element as:

```
    <a href="cancelRequest?userid=<%=idperson%>&userrnamee=<%=namee%>" onclick="cancelRequest();">
        <input type="submit" value="CANCEL REQUEST"></input>
    </a>
```